# Docker compose ERROR no container found for api_php_1

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I have a problem. When I do "docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update" after "docker-compose up -d", I have this message :
"ERROR : no container found for api_php_1".

What is the problem .

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  php:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    # Comment out these volumes in production
    volumes:
      - ./api:/srv/api:cached
      - ./api/vendor:/srv/api/vendor:delegated
      # If you develop on Linux, uncomment the following line to use a bind-mounted host directory instead
      # - ./api/var:/srv/api/var:rw
      - php-data:/srv/api/var/cache
      - php-data:/srv/api/var/log

  api:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_nginx
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    # Comment out this volume in production
    volumes:
      - ./api/public:/srv/api/public:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8888:443"
```

That's not my project and I'm new with Docker

Comment: check you docker container status by using `docker ps -a` if the status `Exited` then there's an error when creating the contianer